# Should I improve the article even the reviewers didn't point out?

Tags: peer-review

A reviewer's comment:

> some sections, such as A, are very short and they need to be expanded or removed; other sections such as B and C are very superficially developed

So I am wondering if I am supposed to revise section only A, B and C or any other sections with same problem?

Comment: I haven't read your paper, ofc, but this to me might also suggest you've created *too many section headers,* when you could do fine with less sections. That said, still take Buffy's answer to heart but something to consider.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I improve the article even the reviewers didn't request to do it?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/190089/should-i-improve-the-article-even-the-reviewers-didnt-request-to-do-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reviewer mentions "sections" (plural), giving A as an example. This seems to indicate they found others too short as well.

But it isn't the length, specifically, that is an issue but whether you say enough to support your arguments in those sections. A section can be long objectively, but still "too short". The opposite is also true of course.

But in your case, the reviewer seems to be asking for more generally, not just in section A. Back to work.

And the "or removed" also needs to be considered if some section(s) is not useful overall. Say more to make it more relevant or consider dropping it.

Comment: Hi Dr. Buffy, thanks for your reply! The whole comment is "Some sections, such as A, are very short and they need to be expanded or removed; other sections such as B and C are very superficially developed", so I am wondering if I am supposed to revise section only A, B and C or any other sections with same problem?

Comment: I would suggest a wholistic approach to the entire paper. And again, it isn't the length, itself, but the development of the arguments in those sections. Also consider which are the most important sections to the overall product.

Answer (score 0):

The reviewer didn't say sections A, B and C are the only sections that need revision. They said there are many sections (with a plural) that need revision, and gave A, B, and C as *examples*. Examples aren't usually exhaustive, which means other sections also need revision.

So the answer is "yes, you should".